# Why error message added via the `$quote->addErrorInfo()` don't show up in the shopping cart?

Tags: magento-1, quote, global-messages

Why error message added via

`$quote->addErrorInfo($type, $origin, $code, $message)`

don't show up in the shopping cart even though it adds the message to `Mage::getSingleton('core/message')->error($message);`,

however, error message added via

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($message)`

do show up in the shopping cart?

Is there a difference between the two ?

Comment: Where is the place you added this line at?

Answer (score 4):

The first

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/message')->error($message);
```

one only creates an error message, but doesn't add item to the messages stack for further showing.

You should add it manually is some way like this:

```
$this->getMessages()->add(Mage::getSingleton('core/message')->error($message));
```

Or use the second one.